# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'lazy' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I followed [this guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) to enable TypeScript for an existing React App. When the app is started the following error appears: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'lazy' of undefined`

React version is 16.8.0 (react, react-dom, @types/react, react-test-renderer).

[image]

**index.js (due to stackoverflow restrictions on size of code vs text not all imports are shown)**

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const AsyncApp = React.lazy(() => import('App'));

/** wrap App component in a fallback component for lazy loading */
const App = (
    <div>
        <Suspense
            fallback={<LoadingScreen />}
        >
            <AsyncApp loggedIn />
        </Suspense>
    </div>
);

async function renderApp() {
    if (document.title !== CONFIG.appName) {
        document.title = CONFIG.appName;
    }
    ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById('root'));
}

/** init app */
renderApp();
```

Comment: what version of react are you using? If its an issue when upgrading to typescript thats probably because you need to import it as `import * as React from 'react'` or you can add the synthetic default imports option in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @JohnRuddell 16.8.0

Comment: I already had `import React, { Suspense } from 'react';` in there but replacing with ```import * as React from 'react';
import { Suspense } from 'react';``` fixed the issue.

Comment: yea, if you're converting to typescript it probably makes more sense to not have to update all of the imports but rather use the flag in `tsconfig.json`. I think its `allowSynteticDefaultExports` or something like that.

Comment: I already have: `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read property 'lazy' of undefined

This means that `React` is undefined. Your file needs to import react. Add the following to the top of your `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
```

If you have the import already then make sure your `tsconfig.json` has `"esModuleInterop" : true`.

Comment: Its not that `React` isn't imported but rather that typescript tries to be "true" about its imports. If there isn't an explicit `default` export then it wont like it. You'd have to import like `import * as React from 'react'`.

Comment: I already had import React, { Suspense } from 'react'; in there but replacing with import * as React from 'react'; import { Suspense } from 'react'; fixed the issue.

Comment: You should not use the `import * as React` anymore as it is not future safe. Set `esModuleInterop` instead. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import React.

```
import React from "react";
```

Comment: I already had import React, { Suspense } from 'react'; in there but replacing with import * as React from 'react'; import { Suspense } from 'react'; fixed the issue.